# What does this regular expression mean?

Tags: java, regex

In a recent interview I was asked to decipher this regex

```
^\^[^^]
```

Can you please help me with it. Also please provide some links where I can learn regex for interviews.

Comment: It would be much clearer if you posted the actual regular expression, not the Java string with its painful and sometimes deceitful bbaacckkssllllaasshheesses.

Comment: @tchrist - why? he said that **this** character sequence was given to him in an interview, a Java related interview, I guess, looking at the tag. (BTW - the regex tag was added by someone else, originally it was tagged Java only)

Comment: @Andreas_D, I hate to admit how many times I’ve screwed up a Java regex because of the backslash problem. Now I read them from a props file or as a command-line argument to (try to) avoid the problem. Even so, there’s a big difference between a Java literal used as a regex and an actual regex. It’s like fighting with the shell, but worse.

Comment: @tchrist:  if you look at the edit history, codaddict has muddied the waters by adding an extra backslash for no reason.

Comment: regexes do not need sequences of two backslashes to escape regex metacharacters, they need one backslash.  **The second backslash is only needed when encoding the regex as a Java string constant.**  The question asks to decipher the regex, not the regex as encoded in a Java string, and there are no surrounding quotes.  I have therefore reverted the regex to that originally posted.

Comment: @JeremyP: **OH!** Thanks for the edit. I very much agree with you about regexes are regexes, and that you shouldn’t phrase them with bogus, bonus backslashes.

Comment: Another interviewer who thought he was *really* smart. Jeez.

Answer (score 30):

It matches strings that *begin* with `^` followed by *any* character *other than* `^`.

So it would match:

```
^foo
^b
```

but not

```
foo
^^b
```

**Explanation:**

[**Caret**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) (`^`) is a regex meta character with two different meanings:

*Outside* the character class(1st use in your regex) it works as *start anchor*.

*Inside* the character class it acts like *negator* **if** used as the *first* character of the character class(3rd use in your regex).

Preceding a regex with `\` escapes it (makes it non-special). The 2nd use of `^` in your regex is escaped and it matches a literal `^` in the string.

Inside a character class a `^` which is *not* the *first* character of the character class is treated literally. So the 4th use in your regex is a literal `^`.

Some more examples to make it clear:

- `^a`         : Matches string beginning
  with `a`
- `^ab`       : Matches string beginning
  with `a` followed by  `b`
- `[a]`       : Matches a string which
  has an `a`
- `[^a]`     : Matches a string which
  does not have an `a`
- `^a[^a]`  : Matches a string
  beginning with an `a` followed by any
  character other than `a`.

Comment: That's true if you assume this regex is inside quotation marks.  Otherwise, it would be a literal '\'.

Comment: @Matt: I assumed that because of the java tag.

Comment: @Matt, I think it's a safe assumption given the fact that if the literal backslash was meant, the regex never would have matched any string.

Comment: Since the regular expression is only matching 2 characters, I think the matching example would be better as it matches "^b" in "^bar" and "^f" in "^foo".

Comment: I really ought to vote down since "Preceding a regex with \\ escapes it" is false.  In a regex only one backslash is used to escape a character.  I'm not voting down because you have assumed the regex is in a Java constant string, in which case regex escapes have to be string escaped.

Comment: @JeremyP That looks like a SO code error - he might have thought that \ was an escape character on SO.

Comment: @JohnL: That's why I didn't vote down.  All the levels of escaping and non escaping makes things quite confusing.

Comment: “Matches a string which does not have an a” is not correct, is it? Should not match "bcd", only any single character other than an a.

Answer (score 3):

I'm testing this regex [here](http://myregexp.com/) however it does not seem to be valid. 
The first `^` denotes the start of the line. 
The first `\` escapes the following `\`. 
Thus the second "^" is not escaped
Finally the first caret inside the square brackets `[^` acts as the negation and second one `^]` is not escaped as a result is not valid.

IMHO the correct regexp should be `^\^[^\^]`
Guys, kindly confirm. Many thanks

Comment: I think there's an implicit assumption that this is inside quotation marks, so the two backslashes are necessary to escape the second caret.

Comment: Thanks for that, just making sure

Answer (score 2):

Match beginning of line or string 
followed by a literal \
followed by the beginning of the line or string
followed by any character that is not a space, return or new line character

Comment: Here is a popular site to learn regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: That is wrong: you cannot have two beginning-of-string/line markers via `^` unless you are in `(?m)` mode.  The most obvious answer is that it’s matching lines that start with a circumflex followed by any non-circumflex character, but this is hard to say because of the stooopid Java slackbashes.

Comment: I didn't say it was correct or would match anything. I just said what it says.

Comment: @Mike Cheel: Most regex engines have four distinct rules for understanding circumflexes outside of `(?m)`, and all are positionally dependent. Under customary rules and `(?-m)`, outside of a bracket character class, only an initial `^` in the pattern counts as a metacharacter; subsequent ones do not. Therefore it cannot mean beginning of line more than once in the same pattern; it becomes a literal. Pretty nasty business, to be honest.

Comment: @tchrist I understand that. As I said I was just saying what the regex says. Throw it into an engine that interprets regexes (I used expresso) and you can see what I said it says is true.

Comment: @Mike Cheel: Looks like you’re right — *sometimes*. It depends where and whether the double backslashes get dealt with. I do see that that regex can sometimes wind up having two Beginning-of-Line (BOL) steps; for example, put `/^\\^[^^]/` alone in a file and run `perl -Mre=debug -c thatfile` on it, and you are correct: there’s a BOL instruction at both steps 1 and 4. But just on the command line with `perl -Mre=debug -ce '/^\\^[^^]/'` ends up with a literal `^` at step 2 and only a single BOL ’cause the shell at a ` \ `. My earlier test didn’t account for differences in backslash processing.

Comment: @tchrist I think that the rub is that there are different engines doing things there own way (similar to browsers) and so while most things should work in all somethings are interpreted differently. A good example of this is at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @Mike Cheel: Do you know how to figure out the contact info for the author of the regular-expressions.info site? It’s several years out of date, and I’d like to get him to update it, but I haven’t found a mailing address for him.

Answer (score 2):

The first `^` is the beginning of line.

The second one is a literal character of `^`  (`\` is to escape the other usual meaning of `^`)

The third one is to say

> a class of characters which does not include the character `^`

Some example to show using Ruby:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "hello" =~ /^h/    # it found a match at position 0
 => 0 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "hello" =~ /^e/    # nil means can't find it
 => nil 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "he^llo" =~ /\^/   # found at position 2
 => 2 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "he^llo"[/[^^]*/]  # anything repeatedly but not including the ^ character
 => "he"
```

Comment: @動靜能量 - you ignored "the second one" in your examples - it will only match if the Strings start with a `^`. And this `^` is part of the match ("^hel^lo" -> "^hel")

Comment: the third case in the example is to show the matching of the literal `^`... is that what you mean?

Comment: @動靜能量 - My mistake, on first reading I thought those example would illustrate the behaviour of the original pattern. (BTW - wasn't who downvoted the answer)